# JAXRS client can't find message body writer

Tags: java, json, cxf, jax-rs

I have a jaxrs client configured like this:

```
<jaxrs:client id="opaRestProxy" name="opaRestProxy"
        address="${endpoint}" serviceClass="com.test.RestProxy"
        inheritHeaders="true" threadSafe="true">
        <jaxrs:headers>
            <entry key="Accept" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        </jaxrs:headers>
    </jaxrs:client>
```

But when I send a request I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: .No message body writer has been found for class : class com.test.RequestObject, ContentType : application/json.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl$BodyWriter.handleMessage(ClientProxyImpl.java:646)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:527)
    ... 47 more
```

My RestProxy class looks like this:

```
@Component
public interface RestProxy {

  @POST
  @Path("/getSomething")
  String getSomething(RequestObject RequestObject);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a specific JSON library?  It sounds like you don't have a provider configured.

Comment: @Patrick how to configure provider for a library like Jackson

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Jackson JSON library you need to add these xml tags to your application context.

```
<jaxrs:providers>
<bean id="jacksonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
</jaxrs:providers>
```

If you are using any other library add that bean to the providers tag. Hope that helps!

Comment: This solution does not work if you're using Jackson 2. I'm looking into a solution.

Comment: @Blamkin86 Did you ever find a solution to this for Jackson 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming using `javax.ws.rs.client.Client`, please register the provider using `client.register(new JacksonJsonProvider());`

Answer (score 0):

This answers point me in the right direction, yet i had to add on two parts to make it work on web.xml

```
 <init-param>
        <param-name>jaxrs.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
            (writeXsiType=false)
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

And on the client call:

```
List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    // add custom providers if any
    providers.add(new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider());
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS,providers);
```