# Replacing @queryparam("") with @beanparam

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, swagger

Within one of my GET service methods I currently have a complex object annotated with @queryparam.

```
public class ServiceClass
{   
@GET
public ResponseClass exampleMethod(@QueryParam("") complexobject compObj)
{...}
}
```

When I change @queryparam("") with @beanparam, and annotate the a field within the complexobject such that:

```
public class ServiceClass
{   
@GET
public ResponseClass exampleMethod(@BeanParam complexobject compObj)
{...}
}



import javax.ws.rs.*;

public class complexobject
{ @queryparam("field1")
  private String field1;
  ...getters and setters...
}
```

I am running into this issue

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.computeExceptionMessage(WebApplicationException.java:205)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.&lt;init&gt;(WebApplicationException.java:179)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.&lt;init&gt;(WebApplicationException.java:244)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.&lt;init&gt;(WebApplicationException.java:133)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1051)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:615)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:579)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:238)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:89)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:152)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:113)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
```

as well as

```
WARN JAXRSUtils:1050 - No message body reader has been found for request class complexobject, ContentType : */*.
```

This is for a swagger integration with an already available API. The reason I have to change @queryparam("") to @beanparam is because when generating the Json it is only annotating the complexobject, however I would need a way for the user to know what fields are within this object and a way they can enter values for these fields. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25536584/2381006

Comment: Are you trying to find an alternative way to define the model as a query parameter or are you looking to break the model into several query parameters, one for each primitive property?

Comment: Looking to break the model into several query parameters

Comment: @VD' I have a jsonProvider already, it is
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />

Comment: Can you share what your dependencies are?

Comment: @JohnAment I am using springframework's dependencies along with swagger's jersey2 dependency which I believe is needed in order to display BeanParam properly on the ui.